# GSON - Human readability

Tags: java, json, serialization, export, gson

Good [insert day phase],
is there a way to export Gson more human readable?

I currently get this:

```
[{"id":"test","region":{"lower":{"x":163,"y":63,"z":233},"higher":{"x":167,"y":67,"z":237}}}]
```

But I would like to achieve results like this:

```
[{
    "id":"test",
    "region":
    {
        "lower":
        {
            "x":163,
            "y":63,
            "z":233
        },
        "higher":
        {
            "x":167,
            "y":67,
            "z":237
        }
    }
}]
```

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [`setPrettyPrinting()`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setPrettyPrinting%28%29) on your gson instance

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
 System.out.println(gson.toJson(yourObject));
```

Comment: Its not working as expected.

Comment: what is the output and what is your expectation ?

Comment: Its printing in single line.

Comment: What is `yourObject` here? Is it a simple json string object?

Comment: @Braj no, it should be your data object that will be converted to JSON representation and it works perfectly

Comment: So we have to construct the object first. Not a good idea just for printing.

Comment: Look at my post there is no need to construct the object first.

Answer (score 6):

Simply try using [JsonParser](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html) in that case you don't need to construct the JAVA object from JSON.

```
String json = "[{\"id\":\"test\",\"region\":{\"lower\":{\"x\":163,\"y\":63,\"z\":233},\"higher\":{\"x\":167,\"y\":67,\"z\":237}}}]";

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement je = parser.parse(json.toString());

System.out.println(gson.toJson(je));
```

output:

```
[
 {
   "id": "test",
   "region": {
     "lower": {
       "x": 163,
       "y": 63,
       "z": 233
     },
     "higher": {
       "x": 167,
       "y": 67,
       "z": 237
     }
   }
 }
]
```